# Python scraping from real state webiste

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape the following page

```
html='https://www.quintoandar.com.br/alugar/imovel/sao-paulo-sp-brasil/1-vagas/de-20-a-75-m2/de-500-a-4400-reais/apartamento')
```

In order to get the rent price, total value and location, which is stored as three lines of text below each pic.

I've tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.findAll('div'):
    if tag.has_attr('class'):
        span=tag.findAll('span')
        print(span.text)
```

My intention is to get inside the div tags with class attribute, find the span classes inside, and then get their text. This is what the inspection of the html suggests.

However, I'm not getting anything. It seems as if there weren't any div tags.

Any clues?

Comment: `SCRAPPING` huh!! Before creating any post, at least try to google for the right keyword meant to be used in the caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site gets the information displayed via JSON API requests like [this one](https://www.quintoandar.com.br/api/search?q=(and%20vagas:%271%27(and%20area:[20,75](and%20custo:[500,4400]tipo:%27Apartamento%27)))&fq=local:[%27-23.307011585653612,-46.728409802832005%27,%27-23.632637895951785,-46.53820899716794%27]&return=id,foto_capa,aluguel,area,quartos,custo,photos,endereco,regiao_nome&size=12&q.parser=structured&expr.distance=floor(haversin(-23.4698247408027,-46.63330939999997,local.latitude,local.longitude))&expr.rank=relevance_score-(10000*distance)&sort=rank%20desc&start=0). It is in fact much easier to parse than HTML, e.g.:

```
url = "some url constructed by substituting chunks in the URL quoted above"
data = requests.get(url).json()
for hit in data["hits"]["hit"]:
    """ hit is an object like this:
        {u'fields': {u'aluguel': u'1100',
          u'area': u'58',
          u'custo': u'1768',
          u'endereco': u'Rua Mariquinha Viana',
          u'foto_capa': u'capa892812990657_7908319390783DSC1351.JPG',
          u'id': u'892812990',
          u'photos': [u'892812990-657.7908319390783DSC1351.JPG',
           u'892812990-262.59010615240265DSC1352.JPG',
           u'892812990-981.8163710707928DSC1354.JPG',
           u'892812990-451.7013311422439DSC1355.JPG',
           u'892812990-173.347171880453DSC1356.JPG'],
          u'quartos': u'2',
          u'regiao_nome': u'Santana'},
         u'id': u'892812990'}
    """
```

Use Developer Tools in your browser (opened by F12) to check for network activity.

Comment: Thks! Could you provide some details? Library to use, etc

Comment: added an example. No extra except requests are needed

Comment: Thks! One last question: can you elaborate on how to get these urls you are constructing?

Comment: if you look at the URL it includes a search query and coordinates of a search rectangle. I think it will be unfair to take away this last bit of work from you

Comment: got it! thks for you help